# how to reset menu dropdown by using angular-dropdown.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-dropdown.js plugin , in my project i taken menu dropdown? when clicked resetbutton menu reset to debult 'menu', how can i achive this one?

here is the plugin "https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation" and here is guidline link "http://angular-js.in/angular-dropdown/" in this ducument not mentioned reset menu function.

please help me any one

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide code. In this instance, provide your controller and your view. Also, one of your links does not appear to be working. This question is really poorly formed; if you want to reset your dropdown then modify the object that it's model is bound to.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a80bxe3p/1/, when i click reset button all dropdown reset to default value  or "ALL"

Comment: This fiddle is not working...

Comment: please click on dropdown menu "http://www.jqueryrain.com/?CxXmcGZi " same thing i achived in my project "https://jsfiddle.net/a80bxe3p/1/" jsfiddle dropdown is not coming but in my project coming , compare both , when you click reset button all links must be rest to default , how can i do?